# Not able to retrive data from Crud Operation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a application written in Spring, Hibernate and SpringBoot,
I have 2 entities class with one to many mapping,
[image]

Here are my LeadUserDb entity class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="lead_user_db")
@NamedQuery(name="LeadUserDb.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM LeadUserDb l")
public class LeadUserDb implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="branchcode")
    private String branchcode;


    @Column(name="reporting_level")
    private int reportingLevel;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserBasicDetailsDb
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="email_Id")
    private UserBasicDetailsDb userBasicDetailsDb;

    public LeadUserDb() {
    }


    public String getBranchcode() {
        return this.branchcode;
    }

    public void setBranchcode(String branchcode) {
        this.branchcode = branchcode;
    }
    public int getReportingLevel() {
        return this.reportingLevel;
    }

    public void setReportingLevel(int reportingLevel) {
        this.reportingLevel = reportingLevel;
    }

    public UserBasicDetailsDb getUserBasicDetailsDb() {
        return this.userBasicDetailsDb;
    }

    public void setUserBasicDetailsDb(UserBasicDetailsDb userBasicDetailsDb) {
        this.userBasicDetailsDb = userBasicDetailsDb;
    }
```

And This is my UserBasicDetailsDb Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_basic_details_db")
public class UserBasicDetailsDb implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String email;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String dob;

    private String mobile;

    private String name;

    private String pan;

    private String pincode;

    private String state;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userBasicDetailsDb")
    private List<LeadUserDb> leadUserDbs;

    public UserBasicDetailsDb() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return this.mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPan() {
        return this.pan;
    }

    public void setPan(String pan) {
        this.pan = pan;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return this.pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public List<LeadUserDb> getLeadUserDbs() {
        return this.leadUserDbs;
    }

    public void setLeadUserDbs(List<LeadUserDb> leadUserDbs) {
        this.leadUserDbs = leadUserDbs;
    }

    public LeadUserDb addLeadUserDb(LeadUserDb leadUserDb) {
        getLeadUserDbs().add(leadUserDb);
        leadUserDb.setUserBasicDetailsDb(this);

        return leadUserDb;
    }

    public LeadUserDb removeLeadUserDb(LeadUserDb leadUserDb) {
        getLeadUserDbs().remove(leadUserDb);
        leadUserDb.setUserBasicDetailsDb(null);

        return leadUserDb;
    }
```

what i want to achieve is to create a query like this one

```
SELECT a.branchcode as branchCode,b.name FROM lead_user_db a
inner join user_basic_details_db b
where b.email = a.email_id and a.reporting_level = 3
```

here is what I have written my Repository class

```
public interface GetUserList extends CrudRepository<LeadUserDb, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT a.id, a.branchcode as branchCode,b.name as name,a.reporting_level,a.email_id FROM lead_user_db a\n" + 
        "inner join user_basic_details_db b\n" + 
        "where b.email = a.email_id and a.reporting_level = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<LeadUserDb> findByReportingLevel(int reportingLevel);
}
```

and this is how I am calling it

```
UserBasicDetailsDb details = GetUserList.findByReportingLevel(3);
```

**NOTE
Getting a new error `Cannot determine value type from string test@dev.com`**

I am getting a hell lot of data, and the actual output have only 2 records

My question is how can i fetch the list of user based on `reportingLevel`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *Why* are you using `String` for structured data such as booleans? Also, never use e-mail addresses as an ID--strings are horribly inefficient, and users want to change them.

Comment: Hi @chrylis i will resolve this